# How to fix nested if/for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement

I'm attempting to change a flag to True when a nested dictionary has more than one key. The code currently counts the number of keys correctly, but it is not changing the flag to true.

I've done both the condensed version below and the more broken out version to no avail. I've also rearranged the statement in multiple ways, but cannot get it to trigger.

```
for page in sd:
        chartcount = len(sd[page])
        print '\n', 'Slide no.', page, '--There is/are', chartcount, 'Chart(s).'
        [combinecheck is True if chartcount > 0 else False]
        print combinecheck
```

I expect:
Slide no. 1 --There is/are 2 Charts.
True

I get:
Slide no. 1 --There is/are 2 Charts.
False

Comment: You are creating a list and not assigning it to a variable. Try `combinecheck = chartcount > 0` Or if you prefer something more verbose: `combinecheck = True if chartcount > 0 else False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do with [] part. That looks like list comprehension (that would be useful if you would be creating a list, which you aren't. And you are not assigning that list anywhere either way.), you dont need that.
Instead put there:

```
combinecheck = chartcount > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[combinecheck is True if chartcount > 0 else False]
```

isn't assigning to `combinecheck`.

Try:

```
combinecheck = False
if chartcount > 0:
  combinecheck = True
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works, but it not quite as compact and elegant as the previous answer.